# How do I recruit Indian and Cavalry units to command during land combat?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

The game says that I can control cavalry and Indian units when raiding a city. I have tried attacking a city but I only see musketeers and captains. I have tried recruiting defeated Indians from ship battles but that doesn't work.

Comment: …Have you *tried* yet? What problem are you having that you need us to help with?

Comment: The game says that I can control cavalry and Indian units when taking over a city. I have tried taking over a city but I only get musketeers and captains. I have tried looting Indians from ship battles but that won't work.

Comment: Oh, so you're question is actually "How do I get Indian and Cavalry units?", not whether you can control them.

Comment: I forgot that the manual was misleading about this, no wonder you were asking a strange question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't; it's a feature that was dropped from the game after the manual was printed but before the game was finalised.

> Q: The manual mentions I can get Indian units to fight on my side?
>
> A: So it does, but it's wrong. The best you can do is to go to a nearby
>   Indian village and convince them to attack the city before you do. They will
>   send out war canoes to do it; just stick close, intercept any ships trying to
>   sink them, then let them enter the port before you do. They'll thin out the
>   garrison and if they are successful, the population as well, without touching
>   the city's wealth. That's where you follow up with an attack against the
>   weakened city.
>
> You cannot actually get to command Indian units in battle, though. That's for
>   the AI only.

Ditto cavalry. It was an intended feature that was dropped.

(Quote source: [Sid Meier's Pirates!: FAQ/Strategy Guide by Sashanan](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/915017-sid-meiers-pirates/faqs/34143))